# Connection between grey scale and intensity in image matrices

Tags: matrix, image-processing

Let A be a image matrix where each element in the matrix displays the integer value of the pixel intensity for a specific pixel. We also have a greyscale between two values.

For example let A be a image matrix symbolizing a 4x4 pixel image. The greyscale of the picture is [0,3] where 0 is black and 3 white.

$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 3\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 2\\
2 & 3 & 0 & 3\\
1 & 0 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Here is where I am confused, mainly in terminology. What element are of intensity 0 and 1 in the image matrix? Does intensity 1 here mean just simply each matrix element containing a 1? Or does intensity 1 mean white and therefore the elements containing a 3 in the matrix are considered of intensity 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example let A be a image matrix symbolizing a 4x4 pixel image. The
> greyscale of the picture is [0,3] where 0 is black and 3 white.

This quote would indicate that, as you suspected, an intensity of 1 means white. Normally, I have seen "intensity" referred to as "brightness" or "value" in programs like Photoshop, Blender, etc. So, in your matrix you would divide everything by 3 to get the "intensity".

You can visualize this with the following code in Python:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_matrix = [[1, 1, 0, 3],
                [0, 2, 0, 2],
                [2, 3, 0, 3],
                [1, 0, 3, 1]]

ax = sns.heatmap(image_matrix, annot=True, cmap="gist_gray")
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is a fairly common way of representing grayscale images. An 8-bit grayscale image, for example, will have a range from 0 to 2^8 - 1, or 0 to 255 for each pixel. An RGB image will have a third dimension for the "intensity" of the red, green, and blue values.

Comment: Perfect, just was I was looking for! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could get similar results with the following code too. The original array:

```
A = np.array([[1,1,0,3],[0,2,0,2],[2,3,0,3],[1,0,3,1]])
```

After scaling the gray-scales to have intensity values in [0,1]:

```
A_scaled = A / A.max()
```

We could it in a more generic way with `scikit-learn preprocessing` module's `MinMaxScaler` (we shall get the same scaled intensity matrix as above):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(A)
# array([[0.5       , 0.33333333, 0.        , 1.        ],
#        [0.        , 0.66666667, 0.        , 0.5       ],
#        [1.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
#        [0.5       , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ]])
```

Now, use `matplotlib.pylab.imshow()` to display the scaled intensities:

```
plt.imshow(A_scaled, cmap='gray')
plt.colorbar()
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]